# How can I clear a TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

I have a pretty decent background in Java and C++, but I'm struggling to do something trivial in C#. I have two `TextBoxes`: `MessageBox` and `SenderBox`. I want to send the text from `SenderBox` to `MessageBox` (which is easy), but I want to clear `SenderBox` once that is done. The following is basically the code that is fired when you press Enter to send the text:

```
string temp = SenderBox.Text;
SenderBox.Text = "cleared";
MessageBox.Text = temp;
```

Most programming languages are somewhat procedural or at least execute in some orderly way. Why does C#/WPF for Windows 8 apps seem to defy this standard? You would expect temp to be set equal to the *value* of `SenderBox`, first of all. If you look at the code, `temp` **should not** equal "cleared" unless that's what `SenderBox` contains. At that point (line 1), it doesn't. I tried to create a `send(msg)` function to dereference the weird string, but that didn't change a thing. The following code runs as expected:

```
string x = "abc";
string y = x;
y = "123";
MessageBox.Text = x;
```

Can someone enlighten me? Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Your code works for me, I can not duplicate your problem, which event are you using to process the enter key? Make sure it is not being fired twice.

Comment: This really shouldn't happen... It works here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not trying to switch the contents of the two boxes, why not just do:

```
MessageBox.Text = SenderBox.Text;
SenderBox.Text = "cleared";
```

Comment: Because it doesn't work for the same reason my code doesn't work. Someone already proposed this then revoked their answer... thanks for trying though.

Comment: Well, I would suggest `MessageBox.Text = string.Copy(SenderBox.Text);` with the caveat that if this works it is a framework bug since they have specified that strings are supposed to be immutable.